# What does ||| mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've googled this and searched through the JavaScript documentation but I can't find any mention of this operator: `a |ǀ| b`

When I try the operator on its own I get an error but when I run the following code it runs perfectly fine:

```js
var a, b = 0; tex = '\u0076\u0061r'
var players, score = 0, x, y, z = 1;
function f(s) {
 var t = 0, r = 0;
    var js = 'window';
    while (t == r) {
     if (t == 1) {
         r = s.length;
            return false;
        } else {
         t += 1;
        }  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         r = 20;i+=9000;eval(s); x = 50; y =+ 8;
            z = -20; y = s;
        }
        if (r < 20) {
         return t + 2;
        }}
     return true;
 } while (f(tex + ' \u01C0='+'0') && score < 900) {
 score = 9000.0001;}eval(y); a = 1; b += a;
 x = 50;{y =+ 8;
}

// testing:
document.writeln(false |ǀ| false); // 0
document.writeln(false |ǀ| true);  // 1
document.writeln(true  |ǀ| false); // 1
document.writeln(true  |ǀ| true);  // 1
```

Changing the values of a and b would suggest it works like `||` but I just can't work out why it works with the previous code, but doesn't work on its own. Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Honestly, questions about spooky mystery behavior really are a waste of time. There's absolutely no practical value here; it's a parlor trick.

Comment: @Pointy I find this particular one funny though :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an operator. It's the `|` operator, twice, with a "Latin letter 'Dental Click'" character in between. That character is valid in JavaScript identifiers. Thus the expression:

```
false |ǀ| false
```

(probably) means the same thing as

```
false | undefined | false
```

because there's no real variable called `ǀ`. (*edit* — Actually there probably is, otherwise you'd get a reference error.)

The `|` (bitwise-OR) operator treats its operands as numbers, and both `false` and `undefined` become `0`.

That function `f()` is what's defining a `window` property called `ǀ`.

Comment: It's not obvious why it turns into `undefined` not a reference exception.

Comment: @zerkms I am not sure why that's true either. It probably actually *is* defined somewhere in the OP's actual code.

Comment: Their code works, and it's not defined. So it's something else :-)

Comment: @zerkms look at that function; it's doing something fishy with `window`, and my inner Sherlock says that that fishy thing is defining a property called ǀ.

Comment: Actually, yep, it does `f(tex + ' \u01C0='+'0')`

Comment: if you format the code, you can see that function ends in `return true;`, and it is calling  `eval()`. maybe it is defining variable `ǀ` inside it.

Comment: @ymonad right - the Unicode (UTF-16) code for `ǀ` is `01C0`

Comment: You kids and your fancy words